# How to set expiring session for single variable

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to set an expiring session variable with django? For example:

```
# user enters password to view item
request.session['session_ok'] = True

# expire this after 30 seconds, so the user has to enter in password again
request.session.set_expiry(30) # <-- Not the entire session, just the one variable
```

How would I do that with the single `session_ok` var? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by a bit of a hackish way. I set a time-expiration for the variable. In this case, because it was a boolean I just set that variable as the time expiration:

```
# set the session expiration for 30 seconds from now
request.session['session_ok'] = int(time.time() + 60)

# check if it is expired
now = int(time.time())
session_expires = request.session.get('session_ok') or 0
if session_expires > now:
    session_ok = True
else:
    session_ok = False
```